# Framework to Insert javascript variables inside html

Tags: javascript, php, html, embed, javascript-framework

I know you currently can't add javascript inside html tags like you add PHP. I.E

```
<h2 class=name"><script>var name</script></h2>.
```

However with the current rise of javascript frameworks/libraries I am guessing there is something that will allow us to achieve this.

If there isn't any, why not ? Are there any security repercussions to this method ?

Comment: Google: javascript template engine

Comment: Why would you want to add code on the fly, that would be a huge security risk.

Comment: @Baine Sumpin can you elaborate the security risks ? Does the template engine mitigate the risk ?

Comment: As long as it is only you adding the code and user input has not influence the risk would be miminal. However, it is not the proper way to place JavaScript on a page, you should use the DOM to insert and change data in an element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most popular JavaScript app frameworks allow you to do that, including:

- [Angular](https://angularjs.org/)
- [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/)
- [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/)
- [Ember](http://emberjs.com/)

If you're looking for something quick and minimal for hacking something together, you could try out [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/).

However, depending on the scope of your project and your interest in learning about JS app development, it'd be a worthwhile investment investigating some of the more fully-featured app frameworks linked above - give [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/) a go!

Comment: thank you for the quick answer. Handlebars seems to be optimal for my situation. Definitely interested in learning React.